# Width for section index titles in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to get the width of the section index titles in a table view?  iOS 9 made these slightly wider.

Comment: There's no API for this. An unrecommended way might be to dig into the table view's private subview structure and find the section index title view.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should make a different question, but I'm doing layout in a table view cell where sometimes the table view may or may not have section index titles.  I'm not sure the best way to find out the available content width of the cell minus the width of the section index titles.

Comment: Just put everything in the contentView of the cell and then you don't need to worry about it. The contentView size will be adjusted as needed.

Comment: I need to know beforehand though for measuring since this can change depending on the content of the table view.