# How to set custom width of tableViewIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change width of tableViewIndex. I didn't find any tableView's method to increase width of tableViewIndex programatically.

I have written this method:

```
- (CGFloat)sectionIndexWidthForSectionIndexTitles:(NSArray *)titles {
    return 100;   
}
```

Please see image

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to change the width? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to change width because there can be text with more characters like "Animals", "Vegetables", "Fruits", etc.

Comment: The whole idea of the index down the side is to only have a single letter, not words. Sort your headings to Animals, Fruits, Vegetables and then show the letters A, F, V.

Comment: However, is there any solution to add as I questioned?

Comment: No, there is no API for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the this question.

[StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533667/width-for-section-index-titles-in-table-view)

There is no `API` for that. Maybe you can handle with any `UIView` manipulation on `UITableView`.